# Get a list of procedures in an Oracle database which a particular user has access to

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I want to get a a list of procedures in an Oracle database which a particular user has access to.
Lets say I have user scott which is owner of 10 procedures. 
user scott has given all privileges to user xxx for some of these procedures.

Now is there any query through which I can find all such procedures which user 'xxx' can access?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple permissions that can be given, so the following query will depend on what you want to test, 
but generally :

```
select * from all_procedures
```

Will provide the list of the procedures the current user has any permissions on (if to compile, and if to execute).

Comment: I want to just the name of all procedures which a user can execute. Is it possible?

Comment: In a normal system, that query should be enough, since people rarely give permission to compile, without the permission to execute. The query of bringing all the actual 'EXECUTE' permissions is pretty complicated since there is a hierarchy of roles that might include permission... Do you really need it? or is he all_procedures enough for your needs?